# MySql Trigger, hard-solution, with Class Inheritance

Tags: mysql, inheritance, triggers

Good evening, I need to create a trigger on cmscore_Items and i would need your help.

The basic idea is :
I would like to do insertations to the appropriate tables according to ClassInheritance

For example, if i add a row with ClassID 4, which inherits from 1,2,3,4
i would like to add records to cmscore_Items, cmscore_Images, cmscore_Documents Tables and so on.

if i add a row with ClassID 5, which iherits from 1,2,5
i would like to add records to cmscore_Items, cmscore_Images.

Trigger so far looks like this: :

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER InsertItem AFTER INSERT ON cmscore_Items 
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN

END; 
$$
```

so, its pretty empty so far:D

Hope you provide me some hits/tips or give me a solutions, cause its pretty critical for my implementation.
thanks a lot

```
ClassID,  Name,   CoreTable,    ClassInheritance

1       Items    cmscore_Items          1
2       Images   cmscore_Images         1,2
3       Document cmscore_Documents      1,2,3
4       Product  NULL                   1,2,3,4
5       Banner   NULL                   1,2,5
6       Article  NULL                   1,2,3,6
7       MetaData NULL                   1,7
8       MenuItem NULL                   1,8
```

Comment: CSV in databases is a road that leads straight to hell, never use it!